# how to get which statements are missed in python test coverage

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest

I am new to python, 
I have written test cases for my class ,
I am using 
`python -m pytest --cov=azuread_api` to get code coverage.

I am getting coverage on the console as [image]

How do I get which lines are missed by test for e.g in aadadapter.py file

Thanks,

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for reporting](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html) in pytest-cov, you can see how to manipulate the report and generate extra versions.

For example, adding the option `--cov-report term-missing` you'll get the missing lines printed in the terminal.

A more user friendly option, would be to generate an html report by usign the `--cov-report html` option. Then you can navigate to the generated folder (`htmlcov` by default) and open the `index.html` with your browser and navigate your source code where the missing lines are highlighted.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the [answer from Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825483/149900), one can also set [`show_missing = true`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#config-report-show-missing) in `.coveragerc`, as pytest-cov reads that config file as well.

Answer (score 5):

To amend @pepoluan's answer `pytest-cov` can also be configured in `pyproject.toml`.

```ini
#pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--cov --cov-report term-missing"
```

Or both, e.g.

```ini
#.coveragerc
[report]
show_missing=true
```

and

```ini
#pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--cov"
```

Comment: For my case using Poetry, setting up [tools.coverage.report] in my pyproject.toml with show_missing=true did the trick